# REST client for Firefox with "Projects" feature (equivalent for Advanced Rest Client)

Tags: web-development, firefox, http, rest

I'm looking for some Firefox extension that works like a REST client equivalent to [Advanced Rest Client](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/advanced-rest-client/hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo) in Chrome.

I already tried the [RESTClient](https://addons.mozilla.org/pt-BR/firefox/addon/restclient/) and [Rest Easy](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/rest-easy/). They work fine, but both  having missing one of best features of Advanced Rest: save the requests grouped in projects.

This is my basic requirements:

> - Send Requests to specific URL with methods POST and GET;
> - Edit the request headers;
> - Save my requests grouped by project (or folder);

Someone knows a good equivalent for Advanced Rest Client in Firefox?